# Why is extend method not working when i call it using list.extend?

Tags: python

When i call the extend method of list in python using list.extend(list_object) i get an error. Why is this happening? Instead of declaring an object of list class i am directly calling the extend using list.extend. the following is the code which i wrote.

```
l=list()
l2=[1,2,3,4]
print(list.extend(l2))# throws an error.I was under the impression that this is same as the below statement
print(l.extend(l2)) #doesnt throw an error
```

Also,

```
class student():
        a=1

s=student()
s.a #prints 1.
student.a #also prints 1. Here the previous error isnt coming.
```

Why is this so?

Comment: You either call it on the class and pass two objects, `list.extend(l, l2)` OR you call it on one object and pass it the other, `l.extend(l2)`. You should understand how classes work.

Comment: Also, in your second example, `a` is a class attribute. `extends` is an instance attribute which happens to be a function. You call it on the list object, not the class (you can, but it's not what you'd usually do).

Comment: `print(list.extend(l2)` should be `print  l.extend(l2)`

Answer (score 2):

Both cases are not the same.

In the first case, you're calling a **method** (a callable attribute) of a builtin class via the class and then an instance of the class. In the second case, you're accessing a non callable attribute of the class, via the instance and then via the class. Methods are callable and in order to call them, you need to respect the signature of the method, unlike the second case.

To use `extend` via the list class itself, you need to pass a list instance as first argument, as vanilla methods in Python usually require an instance as first argument:

```
list.extend(l, l2) # extends l with l2
```

Note that the instance is implicitly passed when you call extend via the instance in `l.extend(l2)`.